# why can't i populate my tksheet table row?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

1. I am trying to get a students attendance record set up in python. I have most of it figured out. I am stuck on one section and it is the attendane section. I am trying to use a table format (tksheets) to keep record of students names and their attendance. The issue I am having is working with tksheets. I can't seem to get the information from my DB(SQLite3) to populate the columns. I've also tried tktables, and the pandastables. But again I run into the same issue.

I have considered using the Treeview Widget to populate the columns with the students names, and then use entry boxes to add the attendance. The issue is I have to create each entry box and place it individually. I didn't like this plan. Below is the current code I am using.

If anyone could show me how to get the data from the DB and populate the spreadsheet I am using that be great. Thanks.

```
    def rows(self):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.sheet = Sheet(self.aug_tab,
                       data=[[f'Row{r} Column{c}' for c in range(36)]for r in range(24)],
                           height=300,
                           width=900)
        self.sheet.enable_bindings(("single",
                                         "drag_select",
                                         "column_drag_and_drop",
                                         "row_drag_and_drop",
                                         "column_select",
                                         "row_select",
                                         "column_width_resize",
                                         "double_click_column_resize",
                                         "row_width_resize",
                                         "column_height_resize",
                                         "arrowkeys",
                                         "row_height_resize",
                                         "double_click_row_resize",
                                         "right_click_popup_menu",
                                         "rc_insert_column",
                                         "rc_delete_column",
                                         "rc_insert_row",
                                         "rc_delete_row",
                                         "copy",
                                         "cut",
                                         "paste",
                                         "delete",
                                         "undo",
                                         "edit_cell"))
           

        self.headers_list = ("Student ID","Ch. First Name","Ch. Last Name","Eng. Name")
        self.headers = [f'{c}'for c in self.headers_list]
        self.sheet.headers(self.headers)

        self.sheet.pack()
        print(self.sheet.get_column_data(0,0))

    #############DEFINE FUNCTIONS###############################

    rows(self)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fAag.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

"""well you should make a function into your code and a button, while you can insert your student name one by one or copy bulk of yor students name into the sheet, this is my code"""

```
from tksheet import Sheet
import tkinter as tk


class demo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.sheet_demo = Sheet(self,
                                height = 500,
                                width = 700) 
        self.sheet_demo.enable_bindings(("single",
                                         "drag_select",
                                         "column_drag_and_drop",
                                         "row_drag_and_drop",
                                         "column_select",
                                         "row_select",
                                         "column_width_resize",
                                         "double_click_column_resize",
                                         "row_width_resize",
                                         "column_height_resize",
                                         "arrowkeys",
                                         "row_height_resize",
                                         "double_click_row_resize",
                                         "right_click_popup_menu",
                                         "rc_insert_column",
                                         "rc_delete_column",
                                         "rc_insert_row",
                                         "rc_delete_row",
                                         "copy",
                                         "cut",
                                         "paste",
                                         "delete",
                                         "undo",
                                         "edit_cell"))
    
        self.sheet_demo.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")
    
 
        self.data = [[f"" for c in range(1)] for r in range(100)]
        self.sheet_demo.data_reference(self.data)
    

        def click_this():
            for i in (self.sheet_demo.get_column_data(0)): 
                if i == '':
                break
                else:
                    print(i.strip())
                    self.data = [[f"" for c in range(1)]for r in range(100)]
                    self.sheet_demo.data_reference(self.data)
                
        button=tk.Button(text=" click this",command= click_this)
        button.grid(row= 1, column=0, sticky= "n")


    
app = demo()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

"""if you want to take data from your database then you must make a main frame and add the button, then make your demo tksheet function as a top level frame, i have made one my own to open my data base, all do you need is change the database in my code with your database. this is my code"""

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime as dt
from tkinter import ttk


def open_window1():
    from tksheet import Sheet
    import tkinter as tk
    import sqlite3

   conn= sqlite3.connect('toko.db')
   c= conn.cursor()

   class demo(tk.Tk):
       def __init__(self):
          tk.Tk.__init__(self)
          self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
          self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
          self.sheet_demo = Sheet(self,
                                  height = 500,
                                  width = 700)
          self.sheet_demo.enable_bindings(("single",
                                   "drag_select",
                                   "column_drag_and_drop",
                                   "column_select",
                                   "row_select",
                                   "arrowkeys",
                                   "column_width_resize",
                                   "row_width_resize",
                                   "copy",
                                   "rc_insert_column",
                                   "rc_insert_row"))

            self.sheet_demo.grid(row = 0, column= 0, sticky= "nswe")
    
            self.headers= ("id","Produk","Stok","Harga Grosir","Harga Eceran")
            self.sheet_demo.headers(self.headers)

            c.execute("SELECT * FROM StokDanHarga")
            h=len(c.fetchall())
            print(h)
            self.data =[[f"Row {r} Column {c}" for c in range(3)] for r in   range(h)]
            self.sheet_demo.data_reference(self.data)
            a=c.execute("SELECT * FROM StokDanHarga")
            j=0
            for row in a:
                # i= len(a)
                r=j   
                print(r,j) 
                self.sheet_demo.set_row_data(r, values = row)   
                j += 1
        


    app= demo()
    app.mainloop()  

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("combobox")
root.geometry("400x400")

buttn = ttk.Button(root, text='STOK DAN HARGA', command=open_window1)
buttn.grid(row=0, column=0)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey this worked great thanks. Now I can populate the sheet with the DB data. The next step is to go in reverse and take the data from my tksheet and populate the DB. Thanks again